# Why does my 2000 ford ranger start when I push the clutch to the floor I just need my key on on and it starts with the clutch

Tags: ford, starting, ranger

It starts when I push in the clutch I understand you need to do that to start the car but I don’t need the key to start I can leave it on on and it starts with the clutch it has a 3.0 v6 engine

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If I've got this straight, you turn the key to the on position (not start position), then press the clutch pedal down and the engine starts without touching the key? Does the starter engage again after the engine is started and you press the clutch?

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem 2007 Ford Ranger V6 vulcan engine. Mine was a bad ignition switch.
Moveable electrical contacts move in every switch positon-Acc, Off, Lock, run and start. Different years I know, but 2007 was also a standard 3.0 v6 engine.Had wiring diagram for the 2007, the run switch position contact was stuck on start.